# How can I remove zombie Panel menu item links caused by Features?

Tags: panels, features

I have a site that uses several panels, each of which has a menu link.  Recently I decided to remove the links on my local dev copy.  I updated my feature (which contains the panels) and then reverted on my host... But the links were still there.

Because the links are provided by Panels in code, they can't simply be deleted from the menu.  How can I delete these links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, disable and then re-enable each Panel one-by-one on the production server.  Hope someone finds this useful!